Can a business in the US allow only customers who are provably citizens of foreign countries?
It would require that customers provide proof of foreign citizenship — a green card, visa, or foreign passport, and would not bar US dual citizens as long as they could prove citizenship in another country.
Would this be legal under “public accommodation” laws?

What product or service does the business provide?  Is nationality relevant?

@phoog It's hypothetical, so let's say it's a restaurant. Nationality as in "citizenship" - the legal status conferred by a country's laws - is the only relevant criteria. "National origin" - what part of the planet your ancestors inhabited - is not relevant.
